# Is it a good idea to break one bigger database table into more tables

Tags: database, view

I am talking about the ecommerce system database scenario where we have orders and customers tables.

Infact there are about 160 fields in one table (Orders) and it contains all, billing shipping info, all order amounts, all extra charges, all credit card and its fraud related info,  all shipping info, all statuses

I am confused, should I break bigger table into more tables, like break it down with following tables, order_payments, order_billing_shipping, order_credit_card_info... etc ?
all these will have one to one relationship

I have to manage this in mysql.I can do that but since it is a big application with huge data I am concerned about performance, I think joins can make it slow...

do you think views and/or index can resolve this issue?

I'll appreciate any ideas for this

Comment: Are you having problems with the current structure? Why do you feel you need to change it?

Comment: And what do views/indexes have to do with breaking a table up? It is not clear what issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is normalized, it really doesn't matter all that much. But if you find duplicated data, you'd probably want to apply the appropriate normalization rules to break it down into separate tables.